# AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via /2023/01/05/post-1 instances

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm adding comment section to my blog which are going to be lessons. For some reason I have this error:

> AttributeError at specific_lesson
>
> Manager isn't accessible via Lesson instances

Error is reffering at the template: `<form action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:lesson_detail' lesson.published.year lesson.published.month lesson.published.day lesson.slug %}" method="post" name="commentform" class="row comment-form">`

I haven't received this error until now and I couldn't find example that is specific case to mine.

urls.py

```
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:lesson>/', views.lesson_detail, name='lesson_detail'),
```

views.py

```
def lesson_detail(request, year, month, day, lesson):
    lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson, status=Lesson.Status.PUBLISHED, slug=lesson, publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    #comments
    comments = lesson.comments.filter(hide_comment=False)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                new_comment=comment_form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.lesson = lesson
                new_comment.author = request.user
                new_comment.save()
                return redirect(lesson.get_absolute_url()) #redirect here
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'You need to be logged in to add a comment.')
        else:
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                comment_form = CommentForm(initial={'author':request.user})
            else:
                comment_form = CommentForm()

    ....# other code

    return render(request, 'lessons/detail_lesson.html', {'lesson': lesson, 'similar_lessons': similar_lessons, 'comments':comments, 'new_comment':new_comment})
```

models.py

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-publish']),
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lang_learning_app:lesson_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
class Comment(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hide_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment "{}" by {}'.format(self.comment, self.author.username)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your views.py file instead of `comments = lesson.comments.filter(hide_comment=False)
` try this `comments = lesson.comments.all().filter(hide_comment=False)`

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your using your model manager "published" inside html thats not going to work. If you want to have access to some manager field you could create a url in your view and pass it to html like this:

```
    lesson_detail_url = reverse('lang_learning_app:lesson_detail', args=[lesson.publish.year, lesson.publish.month, lesson.publish.day, lesson.slug])

    return render(request, 'lessons/detail_lesson.html', {'lesson': lesson, 'similar_lessons': similar_lessons, 'comments': comments, 'new_comment': new_comment, 'lesson_detail_url': lesson_detail_url})
```

then in your html try this:

```
<form action="{{ lesson_detail_url }}" method="post" name="commentform" class="row comment-form">
```